# SELECT IF on mysql condition

Tags: mysql

assume i have 2 tables

this is my fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d8526c5e4eb6e58eb8071b395223d690

shipping table :

```
+----+--------+----------+------------+------------+--------+
| id | origin | order_id | createdAt  | product_id | amount |
+----+--------+----------+------------+------------+--------+
|  1 |      1 |       11 | 2020-12-02 |        234 |   2000 |
|  2 |      1 |       11 | 2020-12-02 |        235 |   3000 |
|  3 |      1 |       11 | 2020-12-02 |        236 |   4000 |
|  4 |      2 |       12 | 2020-12-02 |        236 |   3000 |
|  5 |      2 |       12 | 2020-12-02 |        235 |   2100 |
|  6 |      3 |       13 | 2020-12-02 |        236 |   2200 |
|  7 |      3 |       13 | 2020-12-02 |        239 |   3400 |
|  8 |      4 |       14 | 2020-12-02 |        237 |   2300 |
|  9 |      4 |       14 | 2020-12-02 |        233 |   4000 |
+----+--------+----------+------------+------------+--------+
```

reprint table :

```
+----+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| id | origin_id |      reprintAt      | status |
+----+-----------+---------------------+--------+
|  1 |         1 | 2020-12-03 06:53:53 |      1 |
|  2 |         1 | 2020-12-04 06:53:53 |      1 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+--------+
```

with shipping.origin = reprint.origin_id

basically table reprint is the condition when the origin_id want to print, then the record will be recorded in reprint table

so i want to make a table with the condition if the origin_id are in table reprint, then make it status reprint, else is NULL

so i tried with this query

```
SELECT shipping.origin,  (SELECT IF(
origin_id = shipping.origin, 'REPRINT', '')
FROM reprint
JOIN shipping ON reprint.origin_id = shipping.origin 
WHERE 
origin_id = shipping.origin) status_reprint
FROM shipping
JOIN reprint ON shipping.origin = reprint.origin_id;
```

but it seems not in my expected result

my expected result is just like this based on the table

```
+-----------------+----------------+
| Shipping Origin | Status_Reprint |
+-----------------+----------------+
|               1 |                |
|               1 |                |
|               1 |                |
|               1 | REPRINT        |
|               1 | REPRINT        |
|               1 | REPRINT        |
|               1 | REPRINT        |
|               1 | REPRINT        |
|               1 | REPRINT        |
|               2 |                |
|               2 |                |
|               3 |                |
|               3 |                |
|               4 |                |
|               4 |                |
+-----------------+----------------+
```

explanation : since origin_id = 1 reprint in two times on reprint table, and each origin_id contain 3 product_id, then it must be 3 origin_id with no reprint_status, and 6 origin_id with reprint_status = reprint because for 1 origin_id contain 3 product_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT origin `Shipping Origin`, '' Status_Reprint
FROM shipping
UNION ALL
SELECT shipping.origin, 'REPRINT'
FROM shipping
JOIN reprint ON shipping.origin = reprint.origin_id
ORDER BY 1,2
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=29b745628377648ffba8b1c0835f6a3a)